# Инверсия чисел?

Tags: javascript

В одном учебнике встретил такой термин:
Существует старый трюк с использованием побитового оператора НЕ — ~. Он преобразует число в 32-разрядное целое со знаком (signed 32-bit integer). Дробная часть, в случае, если она присутствует, отбрасывается. Затем все биты числа инвертируются.

- Можно объяснить на простом языке, что значит **"Затем все биты числа
  инвертируются"**?

```js
alert( ~2 ); 
alert( ~1 ); 
alert( ~0 ); 
alert( ~-1 );
```

Comment: Советую как-нибудь окунуться немного глубже в тему как хранятся данные "в компьютере", разобраться что такое биты, байты, как происходит вычисление метематических операций в двоичной системе счисления и как это делает процессор

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инверсия чисел - это побитовая операция, которая по сути делает вот что: 
~a = -(a + 1). 
Её часто используют в условиях вхождения подстроки в строку, так как если это вхождение не найдено, то indexOf вернет -1
Вот пример применения, но это не лучщий пример для повторения, так как код станет сложнее понимать
Пример:

```js
let index = 'test'.indexOf('y'); //index = -1
if(~index)
   alert('Есть');
else
  alert('Нет');
```

Comment: и за что минус, позвольте спросить?

Comment: Я минус не ставил. В каких случаях нам нужно искать подстроку в строке?

Comment: Еще один минус от меня. Вы уж извините, но делать такое `if (~index)` это ни в какие ворота не лезет, если не ставить целью обфускацию кода. Трюки - это хорошо, но учить так делать не стоит.  На мой взгляд объяснение инверсии тоже так себе - слишком зависит от контекста

Comment: а что, собственно, в этом примере не так? Где тут обфускация, все знают этот простой трюк. Инверсия была показана выше, я просто показал формулу, по которой она считается

Comment: А в каких случаях на сайтах нужно делать поиск подстроки в строке?

Comment: когда нужно найти подстроку)) конкретного примера я сейчас не придумаю

Comment: Ну хотя бы простой пример, дабы я понял, зачем вся эта кухня)))

Comment: Ну не считается инверсия ни по какой формуле - просто меняется каждый бит на противоположный. Инверсия одна из базовых операций, которые умеет делать "железо", вся остальная математика на них построена а не наоборот. Приведенная формула просто тождество и только для знаковых типов. Насчет все знают - спорный момент. Ревью такой код прошел бы не у всех. В обычном коде не место трюкам, которые не дают ощутимого прироста производительности или других улучшений

Comment: окей, человек просил пример применения оператора. Вы знаете что-то получше?

Comment: и я не говорил, что внутри она считается по этой формуле, я просто привел формулу по которой её может посчитать человек

Comment: К сожалению, вы при этом не написали об этом. Возможно, я слишком строг, но вы оставили в ответе для новичка не очень хороший пример для подражания. Допустим ответ получит положительные оценки - мы получим программистов, которые будут использовать не очень удачные приемы
PS. Интересно, когда сайт предложит покинуть комментарии и общаться в форуме :\

Comment: согласен, стоило написать, что это не лучший пример для повторения

Comment: Под ответом есть кнопка "править". Обещаю пересмотреть оценку ответа :)

Comment: А можно написать в комментарии ваш первоначальный ответ, хочу сравнить до и после)))

Comment: я просто добавил предупреждение, что не стоит использовать данный пример в реальной разработке

Answer (score 0):

Бит 0 заменяется на 1, а 1 на 0: 0010 → 1101.

Comment: А где обычно используется инверсия чисел, и нужна ли она вообще?

Comment: @Cyrax, в битовых операциях

Comment: А можно любой простой пример этой самой битовой операции?

Comment: ну вон же в ответе пример.

Comment: Я имел ввиду скрипт, где используется побитовая операция.

Comment: В смысле скрипт? Вон у вас же в вопросе есть.

Comment: @Cyrax,  в справке есть примеры использования: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#:~:text=Bitwise%20operators%20treat%20their%20operands,%2C%20hexadecimal%2C%20or%20octal%20numbers%20.&text=Bitwise%20operators%20perform%20their%20operations,return%20standard%20JavaScript%20numerical%20values.

Comment: А в каких случаях на сайтах нужно делать поиск подстроки в строке?

Comment: А почему вы меня об этом спрашиваете? Нужно делать, когда вам это требуется.

Comment: А в каких случаях это может потребоваться?

Comment: Здесь не форум на смежные темы. Если возник новый вопрос, то нужно задавать новый вопрос, а не множить комментарии.